# Implementing responsive images that are dynamic-width, static-height, and DPR-conscious

Tags: html, responsive-design, pixel-ratio

For each post on a website, there will be a header image. This image will have a width of `100vw` and a height of `300px`. I would like to deliver multiple versions of this image via either the `srcset` attribute of an `img` tag or a full-fledged `picture` element (not sure which at this point, hence this question).

Doing so would be rather easy using the `srcset` attribute:

```
<img srcset="lg.jpg 1200w, md.jpg 992w, sm.jpg 768w, xs.jpg 320w" sizes="100vw" src="xs.jpg">
```

The problem arises when I want to account for different device pixel ratios. First, assume I have `2x` and `3x` versions of all of the images listed in the `srcset` above.

Let's say I have a `2x` phone with a `320px`-wide viewport (e.g. an iPhone 5). I'd want the browser to load `xs_2x.jpg`. Likewise, let's say I have a `1x` desktop with a widescreen monitor. I'd want the browser to load `lg.jpg`.

But now let's say I have a larger phone, one with a `3x`, `414px`-wide viewport (i.e. an iPhone 6 Plus). In this case, I'd want my browser to load `sm_3x.jpg`. But, my browser would likely load `sm_2x.jpg` instead because the width of `sm_2x.jpg` (1536 pixels) is closer to the width of the phone (1242 pixels) than the width of `sm_3x.jpg` (2304 pixels). This would result in an image that is not `300px` tall on the device, breaking a requirement of the website.

How can I implement dynamic-width, static-height, DPR-conscious responsive images?

Comment: Have you looked into using a media tag?

Comment: @JaeGeeTee What do you mean a media tag? A CSS `@media` query?

Comment: Yes a @media query.  Sorry I get sloppier as the day goes on.

Comment: @JaeGeeTee While that may be an option for some, it's not an option for me. The image URLs are dynamic and there are a lot of them. There's no time (or bandwidth) to write media queries for all of these images.

Comment: Use `data-` tags always for custom thigns. Why not put JSON in the tag? ? `<img data-images="{ 'small': 'xxx.jpg', 'mid': 'yyyy.jpg'}" src="xs.jpg">`

Comment: @Marcus McLean, in the last but one paragraph you say "414px-wide viewport (i.e. an iPhone 6 Plus)" and "is closer to the width of the phone (1242 pixels)". Where have you seen this 414 and 1242? iPhone 6 Plus' width is 1920px, check it here https://www.apple.com/iphone-6/display/

Answer (score 0):

```
background-size: 100% cover;
```

This should work.

EDIT:
The simple reason why this will work is because you can do it in CSS alone. background-size will cover the available space see article: http://davidwalsh.name/background-size

create a css class: `.img-resp { background-size: 100% cover; }` then apply it to your element.

Comment: Code blocks on their own are not usually useful answers. Please edit your answer and explain what the code you're showing does, and why/how that code answers the question.

Answer (score 0):

You should take into account that JPEG image resolution (DPI) is meaningless for screens. The main thing here is total horizontal/vertical count of pixels.

So 1x, 2x and 3x versions of an image would be (according to device width!):
[image: Device - image size table]

So 1x monitor and 3x iPhone would require the same image (1920 x 300px) and it's code in srcset would be `img_name_1920px.jpg 1920w`

```
<img srcset="img_name_1920px.jpg 1920w, img_name_1136px.jpg 1136w, img_name_768px.jpg 768w, img_name_320px.jpg 320w" sizes="100vw" src="img_name.jpg">
```

Note: if you're on a device with a screen width of 320px and is a 1x (non-retina) display, you should use image with the width of 320px.

Only the total count of pixels is important here.

Answer (score -1):

I did not get exact requirement of you.

I want to give you my code to try for your requirement.
Try this code:

```
   <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en-US">
    <head>
      <meta charset="UTF-8">
      <title>Responsive Images</title>
      <link rel="stylesheet" 
    href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
      <link rel="stylesheet" 
    href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">
      <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js">
      </script>
      <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/js/bootstrap.min.js">
      </script>
    </head>
    <body>

      <div class= "container-fluid">
        <div class="row">

<img src="http://www.technotrigger.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/01/house-in-green-field.jpg" 
   class="img-responsive">
          <!-- <img srcset="lg.jpg 1200w, md.jpg 992w, sm.jpg 768w, xs.jpg 320w" sizes="100vw" src="xs.jpg"> -->
        </div>
      </div>
        </body>
        </html>
```